# How can I toggle my player variable to switch between player one and player two?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a connect four game and right now I'm able to click on the game board; run some logic to determine which slot is open, and then place the current player in that slot. Now I want to switch to the other player. I attempted to do this with a `switchPlayer(player);` function which looked like this

```
function switchPlayer(player) {
    if (player === 'p1') 
        player = 'p2';
    else if (player ==='p2') 
        player = 'p1';
}
```

This didn't do anything because I had player set as a global, so it stays at player = 'p1';

Any ideas?

```js
//grab all slot positions on the board
const slots = document.querySelectorAll('.board div');
const player = 'p1';
const board = [ 
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
]


//assign a class to each slot to represent its position
for(let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
 slots[i].classList.add('c' + i);
 //add the function with the game logic to each slot
 slots[i].addEventListener('click', runGame); 
}

function runGame() {
 //figure out which column the selected slot sits in
 const slotColumn = (Number(this.className.slice(1, 3)) % 7);
 //create an array to store all the slots that share the above column
 const columnArray = [];

 //grab all the slots that sit in that column
 for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  if(board[i] % 7 === slotColumn) columnArray.push(board[i]);
 }

 //drop chip in the chosen column
 dropChip(columnArray);

 function dropChip(column) {
  //select bottom most slot that's available in the column
  for(let i = column.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
   if(column[i] !== 'p1' || column[i] !== 'p2') {
    board[column[i]] = player;
    slots[column[i]].classList.add(player);
    switchPlayer(player);
    break;
   } 
  }

  function switchPlayer(player) {
   if(player === 'p1') player = 'p2';
   else if(player ==='p2') player = 'p1';
  }
  console.log(board);
 }
}
```

```css
/** {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}*/

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #e5e6e8;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

.board-wrapper {
 padding-top: 100px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: auto auto 0 auto; /*ask why this is needed*/
 position: relative;
}

.board {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 max-width: 706px;
 background-color: #00c;
 padding: 3px;
}

.board div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 border: 3px solid #00c;
 position: relative;
}

.board div:after {
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #00c;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px #0606aa;
}

.board .chip {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: transparent;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 100px;
}

.board .chip:after {
 content: "";
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 left: 3px;
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}

.board .chip:before {
 content: "";
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 left: 18px;
 top: 15px;
 z-index: 1;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #cc0000;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all .5s ease; 
}

.board div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover ~ .chip:after{transform: translateX(10px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover ~ .chip:before{transform: translateX(10px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover ~ .chip:after{transform: translateX(110px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover ~ .chip:before{transform: translateX(110px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover ~ .chip:after{transform: translateX(210px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover ~ .chip:before{transform: translateX(210px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover ~ .chip:after{transform: translateX(310px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover ~ .chip:before{transform: translateX(310px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover ~ .chip:after{transform: translateX(410px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover ~ .chip:before{transform: translateX(410px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover ~ .chip:after{transform: translateX(510px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover ~ .chip:before{transform: translateX(510px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover ~ .chip:after{transform: translateX(610px); opacity: 1;}
.board div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover ~ .chip:before{transform: translateX(610px); opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Connect Four</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="board-wrapper">
  <div class="board">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <span class="chip"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Your global is a `const`, thus you can't change what it points to. Change the variable deceleration to a `let`.

```js
...
let player = 'p1';
...
```

2. Your function is shadowing the global name, as such you need to make sure the names don't collide or it will only update the one closest in scope.

```js
function switchPlayer(currentPlayer) {
  if (currentPlayer === 'p1) {
    player = 'p2';
  } else {
    player = 'p1';
  }
}
```

Doing these two changes should solve that problem at least.

---

## Notes

### Shadowing a variable

```js
let a = 1;

function test (a) {
  a = 2; // sets the argument, NOT the same named global
}

test(a);
a; // 1
```

### Other things to look into

- Where you declare your functions

  - Do they need to be declared there, or can they be declared somewhere else?
- How else can you represent the board?

  - Is there a way you can represent the board so that you don't always have to construct an array of things every time?

Games is a great way to build a fun, interactive way of representing JS state related to an HTML DOM! You should try making MineSweeper next!

Comment: Thanks for the help. What's wrong with where I declare my functions? Can you give me an example of how you would do it and why that would be better. And what other way can I represent the board? This is my second version of this game. I wanted to build it completely different from the first. In the first version I just used the DOM for the board and logic. I've seen other people create an array to represent the board, which is what I've done?

Comment: Functions that don't need closure to the previous scope should be declared in a location that makes maintenance easier instead of inside a scope where it would receive unnecessary closure. This way when you go to maintain one function, you don't need to worry about wiping out another needed function unless you want to replace it

Comment: As for presenting the board, instead of using one array to construct another array, why not use an Array of Arrays, which each one array representing on dimension, and the other arrays representing the other directions in a single operation? `Array(width, () => Array(height))` This constructs an array of array to represent `width x height`, and to place a move simply find the index in the inner array, and then set it to the player representation.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared player as `const` , therefore you cannot change the value of it, use `let` or `var`.

Change your code to be

```
var player = "p1";
```

Comment: I'm not certain that's the only problem